# Output voltage issue for TP4056 IC

Tags: voltage, battery-charging, tp4056

I have a TP4056-based charger circuit. My problem: The output voltage of the TP4056 is very variable. The input voltage of the TP4056 is about 5.4 VDC from a DC power supply. The output voltage is between 4.0 and 5.4 V. I changed the input and output capacitors.

Comment: The TP4056 isn't a voltage regulator. It's a two-stage CC/CV charger for Lithium batteries, nothing else. It's not supposed to produce a fixed output voltage.

Comment: I am not saying that it was a regulator, but according to their datasheet it operates as a constant voltage source(4.2v) and deliver it as well. let me know if you solution for that

Comment: Gopi Kammela - You have now written [another question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/643860/tp4056-not-delivered-fixed-output) on the same topic. While it does not appear to be an exact duplicate, you cannot have multiple open questions on the same topic, as one answer might solve all of them, yet people would waste time answering them separately. Therefore I have closed this one as a duplicate of your new question, to avoid wasted effort by site members. Please wait until that question reaches a conclusion, before considering further questions on this topic. Thanks.