# TP4056 not delivering fixed output

Tags: tp4056

When I am trying to adjusts the charging resistor also it doesn't give the output. The output comes like 1.8 V only.

NOTE: I have not connected any load.

Comment: If you are using TP4056 module, check for short circuits on it, maybe that's the case. Any additional information (module you using, input signals) will be appreciated.

Comment: Please edit your question to show the circuit you are using, the supply voltage and a link to the datasheet. Welcome to EE.SE.

Answer (score 1):

> it doesn't give the output.

> NOTE: I have not connected any load.

The TP4056 is a Li-ion battery charging IC. It does not produce a constant voltage output without a suitable battery connected e.g. it produces a limited "trickle charge" current (not constant voltage) when a low battery voltage is detected (see the [datasheet](https://dlnmh9ip6v2uc.cloudfront.net/datasheets/Prototyping/TP4056.pdf)). Without any battery connected, I expect a low battery voltage (actually none) is being detected.

When you connect a suitable battery, you should see the expected CC/CV charging functionality.